# Why does removing an element with javascript prevent iteration of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to replace all text fields on a page with labels.

```
function replaceInputTextFieldsWithValues() {

    var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
        if(inputFields[i].getAttribute("type")== "text") {          
            var parent = inputFields[i].parentNode;
            var value = inputFields[i].value;
            parent.removeChild(inputFields[i]);
            var label = document.createElement('label');
            label.setAttribute('for', value);
            label.innerHTML = value;
            parent.appendChild(label);
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML document is organized in tables. This function only seems to work on the first element in each table.

On the other hand, when I remove the line:

```
parent.removeChild(inputFields[i]);
```

The code seems to work fine. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: The 'for' attribute is meant to be the id of an input field,so that a focus on the label activates its related field. Strictly speaking, a label without a field is not valid. Removing the input gives the for nothing to do. Maybe you should skip setting the for, or hide the input, or even use another type of element besides label.

Comment: @kennebec: Very good point, I have to admit not even having read that far down. @BlackSheep: Absolutely don't use a `label` for this, or if you do don't use its `for` attribute. Use a span with a `data-val` attribute or something (custom attributes with a `data-` prefix work right now on all major browsers, and **[are valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)** as of HTML5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get back from `getElementsByTagName` is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is *live*. (This is true for the other `getElementsByXYZ` methods, but not `querySelectorAll`.) That means if you remove the element at index `0`, the `HTMLCollection`'s length will go down and you'll have a new element at index `0` instead of the one you just removed.

Just work your way through it backward and you'll be fine:

```
for(var i = inputFields.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // ...
}
```

Alternately, convert the `HTMLCollection` into an array and then loop through the array. (See the live example and code below).

**Edit**: **Or**, as Chris Shouts points out in the comments, you can just make use of the changing `length`, but it's not *quite* as simple as Chris' suggestion because you're only removing the elements *sometimes*. It would look like this:

```
var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var i = 0;
while (i < inputFields.length) {
    if(inputFields[i].getAttribute("type")== "text") {
       // Remove it and DON'T increment `index`
    }
    else {
       // Skip this one by incrementing `index`
       ++index;
    }
}
```

Which of these three approaches to use will depend on the situation. Copying to an array gives you a nice static dataset to work with, and if you make sure to release the reference to the `HTMLCollection`, you're giving the browser the opportunity to realize it doesn't have to keep that list up-to-date when things change, which could reduce overhead. But you're copying the references briefly, which increases overhead a bit. :-)

---

**Additional**: Here's an example showing this effect, and also showing a fairly efficient (but obscure) way to create an array from a `HTMLCollection`:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>LI0</li>
  <li>LI1</li>
  <li>LI2</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var lilist, liarray;

// Get the HTMLCollection, which is live
lilist = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Create an array of its elements
liarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(lilist, 0);

// Show initial length of both
display("lilist.length = " + lilist.length);   // Shows 3
display("liarray.length = " + liarray.length); // Shows 3

// Show what the 0th element of both is (both show "LI0" in the live example)
display("lilist[0].innerHTML = " + lilist[0].innerHTML);   // Shows LI0
display("liarray[0].innerHTML = " + liarray[0].innerHTML); // Shows LI0

// Remove the first list item
display("Removing item 0");
lilist[0].parentNode.removeChild(lilist[0]);

// Show the length of both, note that the list's length
// has gone down, but the array's hasn't
display("lilist.length = " + lilist.length);    // Shows 2, not 3
display("liarray.length = " + liarray.length);  // Still shows 3

// Show what the 0th element of both *now* is
display("lilist[0].innerHTML = " + lilist[0].innerHTML);   // Shows LI1 now
display("liarray[0].innerHTML = " + liarray[0].innerHTML); // Still shows LI0
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/idaya3/3)

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to loop backwards, you can always do `while(inputFields.length >= 0)` and always work with `inputFields[0]` inside the loop.

Comment: @Chris: That's a good thought generally, but he has some logic around whether to remove the `input` or not, and so he'd need an index he incremented when skipping, but didn't when removing, and then he'd need to test that against the `length` and it gets (slightly) complicated. Not very complicated (I'm sure we've both done it), but complicated.